# jQuery and json parsing

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON: `{"status":"ok","squares":{"3x13":"0","3x12":0,"4x12":0,"2x13":0,"4x13":0,"4x14":2}}`

How can i translate this to key-value array in javascript?

```
        for (var s in s.squares) {
            console.log(s);
        }
```

gives only keys, like 3x13, 3x12. How get the values?

P.S. Sorry for bad Engish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your loop `for (var s in s.squares)` will iterate each property of the object refered to by s.squares to get the value as well you simply have to do `s.squares[s]` so the loop would be something like:

```
for (var key in s.squares) {
   var value = s.squares[key];
}
```

how ever you'd probably want to safe guard yourself a bit and write the itertion like:

```
var squares = s.squares;
for (var key in squares) {
   if(squares.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      var value = squares[key];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the JSON is a String, you can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert it to a JSON Object. If you have the Object, use

```
for (var key in json) {
    console.log("key:", key, "value:", json[key]);
}
```